# Implement equality outside type definition

Tags: interface, f#, operator-overloading, equality

I have several types that implement an interface. Equality for these types only depends on interface members. Is it possible to define equality for these types once, without overriding `Equals` or `op_Equality` for each type?

**EDIT**

I tried the following, but, for whatever reason, it overrode every use of `=`, even for types not implementing `IEntity`.

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module Equality =
    let inline op_Equality (left:IEntity) (right:IEntity) = true
```

I also tried using flexible types (`#IEntity`). Same result.

Comment: I don't see how to do this with interfaces.It would be easy to do with an abstract base class, but I guess you are already aware of that?

Comment: Yes. I've been experimenting with static member constraints, but haven't found a way to restrict `op_Equality` to types implementing the interface.

Comment: Regarding your edit: only member functions can be overloaded.

Comment: I think operators can only indirectly be overloaded, and only some of them. See [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=NcrMkjVxahMC&lpg=PA132&ots=pkw5MwchbL&dq=f%23%20operator%20overloading%20expert&pg=PA132#v=onepage&q&f=false) for an explanation on the "+" operator. However, "=" is not defined in this manner. It is instead defined to call "Equals" if none of the special cases apply. The implementation of the special cases uses "compiler magic."

Comment: @wmeyer is right - let-bound definitions aren't overloaded.  Operators may end up calling overloaded static members via static member constraints, but the let-bound operators themselves aren't overloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is something that mixins or typeclasses might enable in other languages; unfortunately there isn't equivalent functionality in F#.  Your best bet is probably one of the following options:

1. Use an abstract base class instead of an interface.
2. Write your equality method outside of your type and then have all of your implementations defer to it.  For example,

   ```
   let entityEquals (i1:IEntity) (i2:IEntity) =
     i1.Member1 = i2.Member1 &&
     i1.Member2 = i2.Member2 &&
     ...

   type MyEntity() =
     interface IEntity with
       member x.Member1 = ...
       ...
       override x.Equals(y) = 
         match y with
         | :? IEntity as y -> entityEquals x y
         | _ -> false
       override x.GetHashCode() =
         ...
   ```

   In addition to a bit of boilerplate, the downside here is that if anyone else implements your `IEntity` interface, they aren't forced to use your equality method - it's opt-in.
3. Create an another operator which you use for equality testing of `IEntity`s:

   ```
   let (==) (i1:IEntity) (i2:IEntity) =
     i1.Member1 = i2.Member1 &&
     ...
   ```

   The (huge) downside of this is that structural equality of types containing `IEntity`s (such as tuples, records, etc.) won't use this operator to compare those components, which is likely to lead to surprising broken code.

Comment: I noticed `mixin` and `trait` are reserved words. Any plans? Traits, as in Scala (or perhaps an improved, F# variant), would be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do this in a static way. The problem is that *extension members* (e.g. if you added `op_Equality` as an extension) are ignored by *static member constraints* (e.g. if you also redefined `=` using `inlin` with `op_Equality` requirement).

The F# compiler has some special powers available only when compiling FSharp.Core.dll that could help (search sources for the declaration `let inline GenericOne`). It uses something like static type switch - but this cannot be accessed by mere mortals.

So, I don't have any idea better than using dynamic type test, which isn't really a good approach and it's probably better to define a custom operator for comparison of your interfaces.

For a reference, the ugly dynamic approach would be:

```
let inline (=) a b =
  match a, b with
  | :? IFoo as a, :? IFoo as b -> yourEquals a b
  | _ -> a = b
```

Comment: I was trying to *implement* equality using `inline`, not necessarily *utilize* equality, but good point nonetheless. My goal is to achieve traditional equality semantics by defining equality once for all types that implement the interface.